# How to install Delphi XE on Win7 64bit that has Delphi 2010 on it with least fuss

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, delphi-xe

Any advice or gotchas that I should be aware of. I know to install in a NEW directory, and to have a backup. I will reread the readme file that included in the Delphi-XE installer.

Comment: Installing backward or forwards could end up with file-associations being on the most recently installed version, that you didn't want that way, but file associations are easily revised by end users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never had problems installing a new release of Delphi with an older version also installed.  I have heard that you shouldn't do the opposite (install an old version with a new one already installed) but as far as I know, installing "forwards" works just fine.  And specifically installing XE with D2010 already present has never given me any trouble either at work on on my personal system.

Comment: Installing backwards (older version *after* newer one) is no problem either. You should just take care that the installer does not assign the file extensions like .pas, .dpr etc. to the older product, unless that is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Ive had a number of machines with multiple versions of delphi on without issue, however if you are that concerned, a further thought or consideration is to virtualise your development environments as then rather than reinstall you can "copy" .. Ive put mine into the XP mode machine on my windows 7 for that very reason.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer, a VM solution would work, but I will try a dual version install.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not installing in Program Files (x86).  I created a folder C:\DEVTOOLS which has my Borland, Codegear and Embarcadero folders (among others).  This is definitely the 'least fuss' option.

Comment: Modern delphi's are fine to install in program files

Comment: And it's preferable IMHO, to install it in program files, if only so that your paths and other devs library paths will be resolving to a similar (expected) set of defaults.

Comment: Yes, I probably should have added that I also maintain a parallel install in a backup VM running Windows XP, so keeping a standard DEVTOOLS folder on all systems means that this is indeed the 'expected' default and works with all Delphi versions.

Comment: @David: They're fine to install in `\Program Files` as long as you don't try to edit the built-in live templates, some of which have a lot of room for improvement (or simply customization).